# highest percentage growth

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using Postgres 9.6 and pgadmin 4.

My question is as follows:

Which segment had the highest percentage growth between 2014 and 2015? How much?

this is a join between two tables

table 1: `case_data_order`

- create_timestamp- (timestamp) looks like this for example: 2014-01-01 10:12:20
- purchase_amount- (bigint) the amount for purchase
- id - (numeric)-an id for a single purchase
- merchant_id - same as below.

table 2: `case_data_merchant`

- merchant_category (text) - this is where the difference segments are
- merchant_id-(bigint) an id for the merchant the purchase was made at

I have tried several times but I don't know how to to it.

```
select merchant_category ((purchase_amount_2014-purhase_amount_2015)/purchase_amount_2014*100) 
from (
    select sum(purchase_amount) as purchase_amount_2015 
    from case_data_order 
       natural join case_data_merchant 
    where create_timestamp between '2014-01-01' and '2014-12-31'
  group by merchant_category) as data_2015
```

natural join
(select sum(purchase_amount) as purchase_amount_2014 
        from case_data_order 
           natural join case_data_merchant 
        where create_timestamp between '2015-01-01' and '2015-12-31
    group by merchant_category) as data_2014;

Comment: post what you did so far

Answer (score 0):

You could first select purchase data per each merchant category in 2014, 2015. Then join these data and use RANK function to get ranking per each category.

```
WITH ranking_data 
     AS (
        SELECT q1.merchant_category, 
               q1.purhase_amount AS  purchase_amount_2014,
               q2.purchase_amount AS  purchase_amount_2015,
               RANK() OVER (ORDER BY q2.purchase_amount - q1.purhase_amount DESC) AS purchase_rank 
         FROM   (SELECT d.merchant_category, 
                        Sum(d1.purchase_amount) AS purchaseamount 
                 FROM   case_data_order d1 
                        INNER JOIN case_data_merchant d2 
                                ON d1.merchant_id = d2.merchant_id 
                 WHERE  d1.create_timestamp BETWEEN 
                        '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31' 
                 GROUP  BY d2.merchant_category) q1 
                INNER JOIN (SELECT d.merchant_category, 
                                   Sum(d1.purchase_amount) AS purchaseamount 
                            FROM   case_data_order d1 
                                   INNER JOIN case_data_merchant d2 
                                           ON d1.merchant_id = d2.merchant_id 
                            WHERE  d1.create_timestamp BETWEEN 
                                   '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-31' 
                            GROUP  BY d2.merchant_category) q2 
                        ON q1.merchant_category = q2.merchant_category
        ) 
SELECT 
    merchant_category, 
    CASE 
        WHEN purchase_amount_2015 = 0 THEN 0
        ELSE ((purchase_amount_2015 - purchase_amount_2014) / purchase_amount_2015 * 100 )
    END AS percentage_growth
FROM   ranking_data 
WHERE  purchase_rank = 1;
```